# Suppressing option processing after a non-option command-line argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I am writing a wrapper script using `argparse` which accepts a list of arguments that are going to be passed to another program, and some options that are specific to my wrapper. To avoid confusion regarding which options go where, I want any appearance of a non-option argument to suppress processing further arguments as options, as if a `--` argument appeared just before it. In other words, something similar to what `xterm -e` does.

`parse_known_args` is obviously wrong, because it will ignore unknown options, and pick up options appearing after a non-option.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Python? I would prefer to keep using `argparse` over parsing the command line manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` or `nargs=argparse.PARSER`. The latter differs in that it makes the remaining arguments required.

Neither is particularly well documented as of April 2023: `REMAINDER` is barely mentioned twice in [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) (with no explanation what it does), while `PARSER` is not present in the manual at all, so it looks even more like an implementation detail; perhaps it is not so wise to actually use it.  Beware.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('argv', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_const', const=True)
>>> print(parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a', '--foo', 'b']))
Namespace(argv=['a', '--foo', 'b'], foo=True)
>>> print(parser.parse_args(['--foo']))
Namespace(argv=[], foo=True)
```

---

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('argv', nargs=argparse.PARSER)
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_const', const=True)
>>> print(parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a', '--foo', 'b']))
Namespace(argv=['a', '--foo', 'b'], foo=True)
>>> print(parser.parse_args(['--foo']))
usage: [-h] [--foo] argv ...
: error: the following arguments are required: argv
```